# how to prevent source not found when using fragment

Tags: android

i'm new in using fragments.. i'm trying to make simple fragment app here.. but when i try to run on device.. i got the "Source not found" and edit source lookup.. can anyone help? thanks..
i change nothing in my mainActivity.java

here is the layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.test2.MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/text_fragment"
    android:name="com.example.fragmentexample.TextFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout="@layout/text_fragment" />
```

and text_fragment.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

Comment: post the error log your're getting

Comment: i'm not sure, because when i run the app, the error log doesn't add any error.. but if i look in the error history, i think it is "Current file is not a match for the given config."